# How should I ask a why doesn't it work for me question?

Tags: support

I am trying to implement the code outlined in the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504465/entityframework-code-first-custom-connection-string-and-migrations/15847388?noredirect=1#comment22676043_15847388)  but am having further problems with it.

Should I ask a separate question that links back to this question, or should I just keep adding comments?

I ask this because I have asked quite a few questions trying to get to the bottom of my problem , and I just cant seem to get an answer that works for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ask a new question, linking to the original.

Detail everything you have tried, explain what is not working. Code, errors and exceptions are the most important things to include.

Explain your specific circumstances, if different from those of others. Link to things you have tried, explaining what you tried there.